# Material UI Snackbar autoHideDuration as null

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to implement a dynamic Material UI Snackbar that can either have a specific time to "auto-hide" or not. This information will come as `props` when I call my custom component.

About the `autoHideDuration` property, the documentation says:

> The number of milliseconds to wait before automatically calling the `onClose` function. `onClose` should then set the state of the open prop to hide the Snackbar. This behavior is disabled by default with the `null` value.

I know that if I omit this parameter, my Snackbar will **not** auto-hide. But if I try to specify this parameter with a `null` value, I get a Type Error:

> Type `null` is not assignable to type `number`

Here is the relevant part of the code I have:

```
const SnackbarComponent = (props: SnackbarProps) => {
  const autoHideValue = props.stayOpen ? null : 4000;

  return (
    <Snackbar
        open={ture}
        autoHideDuration={autoHideValue} // Type Error on this line
        onClose={handleClose}
    />
  );
};
```

And I call it like this:

`<SnackbarComponent stayOpen={true} />`

---

The only solution that I could think of, is to have a conditional return. But this doesn't seem like the best way to do it:

```
const SnackbarComponent = (props: SnackbarProps) => {
  if(props.stayOpen){
    return (
      <Snackbar
        open={ture}
        onClose={handleClose}
      />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Snackbar
        open={ture}
        autoHideDuration={4000}
        onClose={handleClose}
      />
    );
  }
};
```

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const SnackbarComponent = (props: SnackbarProps) => {
  const snackbarProps = {
     open: true,
     onClose: handleClose,
     // this condition solves your problem
     ...(props.autoHideDuration && { props.autoHideDuration })
     // or with default value
     // ...(!props.stayOpen && { autoHideDuration: 4000 })
  }

  return <Snackbar {...snakbarProps} />;
};
```

Comment: Thanks @zemil. I ended up using the "default value" option. Only a small mistake there, since my `props.stayOpen` returns `true` when I want it to **not** auto-hide, the code should be:
`(!props.stayOpen && { autoHideDuration: 4000 })` (with a negative)
If you don't mind fixing that in your answer, just in case someone else has a similar issue :)